# Tesseract fine tuning Cant open lstmbox

Tags: ocr, tesseract, windows-subsystem-for-linux

im trying to fine tune tesseract 4.1.1 in my WSL shell. Doing that im following [this](https://www.statworx.com/en/content-hub/blog/fine-tuning-tesseract-ocr-for-german-invoices/)
tutorial.
I have created a number of .tiff files and now are trying to generate the corresponding .box files using lstmbox.
```
tesseract my_picture.tiff my_picture --psm 2 eng lstmbox
```
But instead of giving me the corresponding .box files i am hoping for, tesseract just returns the following:
```
read_params_file: Cant't open lstmbox
```
After looking trough some tesseract related content i think that I'm maybe just missing a part of tesseract that wasn't installed the right way. But I am not sure and can't find which one it might be.
Does somebody once had the same problem or just knows how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Error `read_params_file: Cant't open...`  means that tesseract can not find defined configuration file (`lstmbox`). If your installation process did not installed it you can download it (and others) from https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/tree/main/tessdata/configs and install it manually to your installation structure.